# How do I open a shell by default in my emacs' init file?

Tags: emacs

When I start up emacs, I'd like to have a shell loaded up right away. Is there a way to do this by changing my .emacs file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just put `(shell)` to the end of my `.emacs` file and it opens right after emacs start up.

Answer (score 1):

On a fresh install of Emacs 27.1, I had to do the following:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t))
(switch-to-buffer (shell))
(delete-other-windows)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this question for more recent versions of emacs!